How to get the new item name when I perform an update in Room?
I have 5 items in Room and I want to update the name of one item. Here is what I have tried:
interface ItemDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM item_table")
    fun getItems(): Flow<List<Item>>

    @Update
    fun updateItem(item: Item)
}

My repo is very simple:
interface ItemRepository {
    fun getItems(): Flow<List<Item>>

    fun updateItem(item: Item)
}

Inside the ViewModel I do:
class ItemsViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repo: ItemRepository
) : ViewModel() {
    private val _result = MutableStateFlow<Result>(Result.Loading)
    val result: StateFlow<Result> = _result
        .onStart {
            getItems()
        }.stateIn(
            viewModelScope,
            SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000L),
            Result.Loading
        )

    private fun getItems() = viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            repo.getItems().collect { items ->
                _result.value = Result.Success(items)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            _result.value = Result.Error(e)
        }
    }

And inside the composable I do:
val result = viewModel.result.collectAsStateWithLifecycle().value

Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        //  
    },
    content = {
        when(result) {
            is Result.Loading -> CircularProgressIndicator()
            is Result.Success -> {
                items(
                    items = result.items
                ) { item ->
                    Text(item.name)
                }
            }
            is Result.Error -> print(result.e)
        }
    }
)

When I open the app, I get all the data from Room correctly. When I update the name of the first item, I cannot see the updated name, unless I close and reopen the app. Why isn't the state changed when I update the name in Room? How to solve this?

this is because you have set the data already, after updating any entry you need to use observe to update the list of items

@JayantaSarkar Ok, and how can I see the updated item? How to change the code? Any ideas? Thanks.

I'm not even sure what exactly happens in your ViewModel but there is an established way to convert data Flow into StateFlow.

convert Flow<List<Item>> into Flow<Result> using map
catch exceptions with catch and emit caught errors wrapped in Result.Error
convert Flow<Result> into StateFlow<Result> using stateIn

val result: StateFlow<Result> = repo.getItems()
    .map { items -> Result.Success(items) as Result }
//    .map<List<Item>, Result> { Result.Success(it) }   // alternative map syntax
    .catch { e -> emit(Result.Error(e as Exception)) }
    .stateIn(
        viewModelScope,
        SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5_000L),
        Result.Loading
    )

You can also combine several flows with combine, like described in the docs.

The problem is onStart method in Flow. your answer is correct.

Thank you, Jan for taking the time to answer my question but I get the same behavior. When I update an item, I cannot see the change unless I restart the app. The change doesn't have any effect.

Could you update what does your ViewModel look like now? Also please include the item updating part of the composable and ViewModel. @AlwaysLearner

The problem is onStart method in Flow<T> is called before the flow starts emitting objects and before the upstream flow is started.
so you can change
  val result: StateFlow<Result> = repo.getItems()  
    .map<List<Item>, Result> { Result.Success(it) } 
    .catch { emit(Result.Error(it)) }
    .stateIn(viewModelScope, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000),Result.Loading)

for more details refer architecture-templates

Thank you, Sasi for taking the time to answer my question but I get the same behavior. When I update an item, I cannot see the change unless I restart the app. The change doesn't have any effect.
